# SQL Query for 1 hour data using the datetime format YYYYMMDDHHMMSS

Tags: sql

How to query for 1 hour data, my date-time format is `YYYYDDMMHHMMSS`?

example:

```
20120720094318
20120720121318
20120720144028
```

Tried finding the query online still doesn't work.

Tried:

```
enddate >= FORMAT(DATEADD(dd,-1,GETDATE()), 'yyyyMMdd000000')
```

I would like something like this:-

Sample data:

```
Cup     machine     end date
123      BB1         20120720092318
333      BB1         20120720094418
444      BB1         20120720084218
555      BB1         20120720082318
```

if i run the query @ 10am on above sample data i should have

```
Cup     machine     end date
123      BB1         20120720092318
333      BB1         20120720094418
```

which means to get record between 9am - 10am

Comment: Tag dbms used. Many dbms products are far from ANSI SQL compliant when it comes to date/time.

Comment: What is the actual datatype of the field?

Comment: I edited my answer according to your self-answer. Btw: You should not add more information by answering but rather edit your original question (without changing the original intent).

Comment: actually i've already have data in my record(which is more than 1000) .i just need to pull last 1 hour record base on the enddate(which is the machine outout timing for that particular row).
the format for my enddate record is YYYYMMDDHHMMSS

Comment: @nonameisme If you use this format it is **not** a **real** date-time datatype but a string or a big number. It is possible to deal with these values without conversion - but then: What is your question? If you just have to pull the last hour, you might change the `WHERE` in my example to `WHERE EndConverted >= DATEADD(HOUR,-1,GETDATE())'

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this (working in SQL-Server):

This converts your date to "real" date-time datatype.

You might do this with alphanumeric values, but I wouldn't...

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(Cup INT,machine VARCHAR(100),[end] VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
 (123,'BB1','20120720092318')
,(333,'BB1','20120720094418')
,(444,'BB1','20120720084218')
,(555,'BB1','20120720082318');

;WITH Converted AS
(
    SELECT Cup,machine,[end]   
          ,CONVERT(DATETIME,STUFF(STUFF(STUFF([end],9,0,' '),12,0,':'),15,0,':')) AS EndConverted 
    FROM @tbl      
)
SELECT *
FROM Converted
WHERE EndConverted BETWEEN {ts'2012-07-20 09:00:00'} AND {ts'2012-07-20 10:00:00'}
```

The result

```
Cup machine end             EndConverted
123 BB1     20120720092318  2012-07-20 09:23:18.000
333 BB1     20120720094418  2012-07-20 09:44:18.000
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an effective/efficient way to truncate getdate() to just the current day, it gets the numbers of days since the calendar 0 reference date (1900-01-01), then it adds that number of days to the 0 reference date.

```
dateadd(day, datediff(day,0, getdate() ), 0)
```

then add the current hour to that using *hour(getdate())*

```
dateadd(hour,hour(getdate()),dateadd(day, datediff(day,0, getdate() ), 0))
```

so we arrive at the starting point of the range. To get the other end of the range, just add 1 more hour like so:

```
dateadd(hour,hour(getdate())+1,dateadd(day, datediff(day,0, getdate() ), 0))
```

then:

```
enddate >= FORMAT(dateadd(hour,hour(getdate()),dateadd(day, datediff(day,0, getdate() ), 0)), 'yyyyMMdd000000')
and enddate < FORMAT(dateadd(hour,hour(getdate())+1,dateadd(day, datediff(day,0, getdate() ), 0)), 'yyyyMMdd000000')
```

If it turns out your enddate column is a true datetime column, do NOT use the format() function because you can directly compare a datetime column to the calculated datetime value we have derived from getdate()

i.e. dateadd() returns a datetime

```
enddate >= dateadd(hour,hour(getdate()),dateadd(day, datediff(day,0, getdate() ), 0))
and enddate < dateadd(hour,hour(getdate())+1,dateadd(day, datediff(day,0, getdate() ), 0))
```

note: I don't use or recommend using *between* for date ranges, use the combination >= with < instead.

---

To truncate getdate() an alternative approach is to use *cast(getdate() as date)* and with that as the basis you could use:

```
enddate >= FORMAT(dateadd(hour,hour(getdate()), cast(getdate() as date)), 'yyyyMMdd000000')
and enddate < FORMAT(dateadd(hour,hour(getdate())+1, cast(getdate() as date)), 'yyyyMMdd000000')
```

or, if not a varchar column but datetime:

```
enddate >= dateadd(hour,hour(getdate()), cast(getdate() as date))
and enddate < dateadd(hour,hour(getdate())+1, cast(getdate() as date))
```